# How to remove magic effects in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Specifically "Fortify Stamina". I decided to enchant a ring in Skyrim with Fortify Stamina, but when I tried to equip the ring it wouldn't work and I clicked it multiple times trying to equip the item. Later I realized I had 500 points of stamina.

This broke the game and I don't know how to get rid of the effect.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of possible solutions, starting with the *least invasive* option. You should stop following these instructions as soon as you have solved the problem. **Make a permanent save before doing any of the following things.**

1. Save and load. Your stamina may fix itself automatically.
2. Reload a save from before the effect was applied.
3. Equip and then unequip the ring, to reapply and then remove the enchantment effect.
4. Open the console, click on an empty container which you own (e.g. in a player house), note its refid (the hexadecimal number that appears when you click on it), and then type `player.removeallitems <refid>`. This moves everything into the container, and implicitly unequips all items. If you somehow have duplicate copies of the ring equipped, this removes them.
5. `player.dispelallspells` will remove all "temporary" spells on your character. It normally does not work on enchantments, because they're supposed to go away when you unequip the item in question. It also does not work on "permanent" buffs, which must instead be removed individually with `player.removespell <spell ID>`.
6. You can fix it manually using `modav` commands, but this is somewhat more complex. Basically, use `player.getavinfo stamina` to figure out what happened to your stamina attribute, and then undo it:

   - If you have an unwanted *temporary modifier*, this should have gone away with `player.dispelallspells`. Try doing that again.
   - If you have an unwanted *permanent modifier*, this means that some permanent enchantment or magic effect is causing it. You can increase or decrease the permanent modifier using `player.modav stamina <amount>`, but it may be preferable to try and find the underlying magic effect and dispel or remove it.
   - If you have somehow gained more than the maximum amount of stamina, you can fix this with `player.damageactorvalue stamina <amount>`.